# IOS App : Is it possible to have 2 Bluetooth connections in one app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm in the process in developing an App That receives data from a Bluetooth accessory and does some processing for the data and then send a simple command to a Bluetooth-Low Energy(BLE)  Module which is connected to an arduino . 
So far I managed to develop and app for the Bluetooth accessory and another app which sends commands to the BLE module.
The question is it possible have 2 Bluetooth devices connected to an iphone ? and is it also possible do develop an app that has 2 app delegates where there is one for the accessory and the BLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are able to connect to multiple BLE chip bearing devices using the Core Bluetooth framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I just wanted to point out that I'm using the external accessory for the 1st app and the core Bluetooth framework for the other so wont they be effecting each other by any chance ??